# Generate number 30% +- average number

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to create a random generator that takes a double value and outputs a new number that is either 30% over or under the input?

```
var result =  4 + random.NextDouble(); //output 4.2324355
var OverOrUnder = result + or - 20%

//Output to 1 decimal place
Console.WriteLine(OverOrUnder)
```

Also how can I print the result so that it's only printing to 1 decimal place

Comment: A few questions: The *input* double value is not random, but provided to the function, right? Does it have to be exactly +/- 30% and only whether is + or - is random. Or do want any random from -30% to +30%?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe

```
public static Random r = new Random();

public static double NextDouble(double value)
   => r.NextDouble() * (value * 1.3 - value * 0.7) + value * 0.7;
```

Or with an optional multiplier parameter and some simplifier math

```
public static double NextDouble(double value, double percent = 0.3)
   => r.NextDouble() * (2 * value *  percent) + value * (1 - percent);
```

**Example**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   Console.WriteLine(NextDouble(100));

// Or for 1 decimal place

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   Console.WriteLine($"{NextDouble(100):N1}"))
```

**Output**

```
102.433669200369
83.64005585836249
116.86387416294957
88.28468969011898
77.75586905319051
83.67046313996914
115.69185544070407
104.68552079735582
122.76178736833938
82.53277266981675
```

...

```
78.9
108.2
72.4
91.4
87.7
116.1
96.4
124.8
120.5
101.0
```

Comment: Can you explain what 1.3 and 0.7 are? sorry just trying to understand

Comment: @DaveDave 1.3 is plus 30 percent, 0.7 is minus 30 percent

Comment: ah i see thank you! do you know how I can print it so that it's only to 1 decimal point? e.g. 102.3

Comment: Just a comment `(value * 1.3 - value * 0.7) == value * 0.6`. And in analog `(value * (1 + percent) - value * (1 - percent)) == value * 2 * percent`

Comment: @derpirscher Yup thanks :) Yeah, i considered that when i wrote the answer, i thought this was easier to see what's happening. Ill update when i get a chance

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double input = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var random = new Random();
        var overOrUnder = input + (random.NextDouble() - 0.5) * input * 0.3 * 2;

        Console.WriteLine($"{overOrUnder.ToString("0.0")}");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Random random = new Random();
    var result = input + (random.NextDouble() - 0.5) * input * 0.3 * 2;
     //To print upto 1 decimal point
    Console.Write(string.Format("{0:0.0}",Math.Truncate(result*10)/10));
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

If the 30% is fixed and just the sign is random you can try like this. `random.NextInt(2)` will generate either `0` or `1`. And based on that it will multiply the `input` with either `0.7` (ie -30%)  or `1.3` (ie +30%)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double input = 27.34;
    var random = new Random();
    var newvalue = input * (random.NextInt(2) == 0 ? 0.7 : 1.3);

    Console.WriteLine(newvalue.ToString("0.0"));
}
```

For formatting a double to your needs, see the docs of [double.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_Double_ToString_System_String_) and either use a fixed format or a custom format for your needs.